# JPA SQL Server Batch Inserts

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

### Problem Statement

I am trying to improve the performance of an insert process in JPA.  Currently it takes 4 minutes to insert ~350,000 records into my database.  To speed up performance I want to use batch inserting.  I have made an outline that shows the code I started with.  The modifications I made to try and improve performance as well as fix memory issues.  The results of those modifications.  And some of my other attempts not shown in modifications.  Please let me know how I can improve my code to allow for large amounts of inserts using sql server and hibernate.  I can provide more information about the overall insert process if needed.

### Starting Code

to enable this, in the application.yml I put:

```
jpa:
  properties:
    hibernate:
      jdbc:
        batch_size: 1000
        batch_versioned_data: true
      order_inserts: true
```

I started with code that looks like this in my Loader class:

```
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines("/path/to/file")) {
    Iterators.partition(lines.iterator(), 1000).forEachRemaining(batchList -> {
        List<CustomEntity> mappedEntities = list.stream().map(mapLineToEntity).collect(Collectors.toList());

        //Insert batch
        repository.saveAll(mappendEntities);
        repository.flush();
    })
}
```

### Code Modifications

But this has caused memory issues, prompting a custom sql implementation using EntityManager to flush and clear the persisted entities.  To do this I created a CustomEntityServiceCustom.java interface and its implementation.  Here are my two attempts below with the modified Loader class:

```
public interface CustomEntityServiceCustom {
  void batchInsertProcess(List<CustomEntity> customEntities, int start); //try 1 
  void batchInsertProcess(List<CustomEntity> customEntities, AtomicInteger start); //try 2
}

public class Custom CustomEntityServiceCustomImpl implements CustomEntityServiceCustom {
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  //Try 1
  @Override
  @Transactional
  void batchInsertProcess(List<CustomEntity> customEntities, int start) {
    for(CustomEntity ent : customEntities) {
      em.persist(ent)
    }
    em.flush();
    em.clear();
  }

  //Try 2
  @Override
  @Transactional
  void batchInsertProcess(List<CustomEntity> customEntities, AtomicInteger start) {
    final int numRecsPerInsert = 25;
    Iterators.partition(customEntities.iterator(), numRecsPerInsert).forEachRemaining(batchList -> {
      /*
      code not included but createInsert will create an insert statement like the following:
      INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (rec1val1, rec1val2), (rec2val, rec2val2)
      for 25 records at a time and then update the AtomicInteger 
      */
      String multiLineInsert = createInsert(batchList, start.get());
      start.addAndGet(numRecsPerInsert);
      em.createNativeQuery(multiLineInsert).executeUpdate();
    })
    em.flush();
    em.clear();
  }
} 

//updated loader

try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines("/path/to/file")) {
    AtomicInteger start = new AtomicInteger(1);
    Iterators.partition(lines.iterator(), 1000).forEachRemaining(batchList -> {
        List<CustomEntity> mappedEntities = list.stream().map(mapLineToEntity).collect(Collectors.toList());
    repository.batchInsertProcess(mappedEntities, start);
    })
}
```

Both try 1 and 2 took advantage of not using the autogenerated ids by not using:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

### Current Metrics

With all these changes there was no significant performance improvement from the starting code.
Try 1 was achieving an insert of ~50,000 records in 35 seconds and Try 2 was performing same insert in 1 min.  I do not understand this as Try 1 was inserting 1 record at a time like:
INSERT INTO table (COL1, COL2) VALUES (VAL1, VAL2); whereas Try 2 was inserting 25 records in 1 statement.  I also tried 4 records per insert as recommended [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/comparing-multiple-rows-insert-vs-single-row-insert-with-three-data-load-methods/) but this was still 52 seconds which is much larger than the 35 without using batch inserts.

### Other Considerations

I attempted to allow hibernate handle the multiple records per statement following [This](https://medium.com/@jerolba/persisting-fast-in-database-1af4a281e3a) but I do not see an option for SQL Server to rewriteBatchedStatements.  I have tried adding useBulkCopyForBatchInsert=true; to the connection string as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/use-bulk-copy-api-batch-insert-operation?view=sql-server-ver15), but am unsure if I will have to modify my code to see the benefits of this change?

I also am unsure if EntityManager needs to be flushed after exectuteUpdate() since in logs I got a message that 0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes and 6596474 nanoseconds spent executing 2074 partial flushes.  This could be another bottleneck, but Im not sure exactly what happens behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the insert statement with a multi-values clause like this, you will probably do hard-parses all the time. You should be using parameters instead so that the statement is cached on the server side. Also, you should reuse the `Query` object and just re-bind values. This is what Hibernate does for you behind the scenes when using batch inserting. Also, it will use the JDBC Batch API which can do some tricks on the protocol level as well to improve performance further.

To wrap this up, I don't think that a multi-values clause can be better than batch inserts through the JDBC Batch API. If that really performs better, I'd say it's a bug in the JDBC driver and should be fixed. Even if the fix is to just use the multi-values clause statement behind the scenes.

Anyway, if you want to try it out, you should probably structure this in the following way:

```
  @Override
  @Transactional
  void batchInsertProcess(List<CustomEntity> customEntities, AtomicInteger start) {
    final int numRecsPerInsert = 25;
    // creates "insert into ... values (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), ..."
    String multiLineInsert = createInsert(numRecsPerInsert);
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(multiLineInsert);
    Iterators.partition(customEntities.iterator(), numRecsPerInsert).forEachRemaining(batchList -> {
      bindValues(query, batchList, start.get(), numRecsPerInsert);
      start.addAndGet(numRecsPerInsert);
      query.executeUpdate();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Christian.  So you are saying that.
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2), (val3,val4) provides no significant benefit over INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2) twice?  I am a little curious how the Batch API works as the generated SQL shows only the insert statements and no BATCH keyword.  SQL Server appears to perform Batch inserts with a csv file.  Is this the only way to perform large Batch inserts?

Comment: The performance benefit comes from reusing the same server side prepared statement and just sending values to that handle in a batch. There is no logging for that I think. The code for the SQL Server JDBC driver is open source, so you can take a look here: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerPreparedStatement.java#L1916